# GitHub doesn't reflect pandas styles

Tags: pandas, github

GitHub does not reflect the styles that I applied to the dataframe using the pandas method style().

```
    datapivothappiness_score[datapivothappiness_score.index.isin (short_list)].style\
    .background_gradient(cmap='Greens')\
    .format(precision=1, thousands=".", decimal=",")
```

At VSCode it warks good
[image: VSCode]
But not at GitHib
[image: GitHub]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that GitHub is not displaying the styles properly due to the fact that it's a static HTML rendering of your code and not an interactive notebook that can fully display the styles. You can try converting your notebook to another format such as HTML or PDF if you want to view your dataframe with the applied styles.

Alternatively, you can try using the `to_html` method to convert your styled dataframe to HTML and then display the HTML on GitHub. Here is an example of how to do this:

```py
styled_df = datapivothappiness_score[datapivothappiness_score.index.isin (short_list)].style\
    .background_gradient(cmap='Greens')\
    .format(precision=1, thousands=".", decimal=",")
    
html = styled_df.render()

# Save the HTML to a file
with open('styled_dataframe.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

# Display the HTML on GitHub (must be placed within backticks)
print(f'`{html}`')
```

Then, copy and paste the HTML output within the backticks into a Markdown cell in your GitHub README file, and it should display properly.

Note that this method will only display the styled dataframe as a static HTML table and will not have any interactive features.